# Transformar numero (####) em hora e minutos (HH:MM) no R

Tags: r, data

Olá, preciso transformar o formato 0000(Inteiro) no formato HH:MM (time), no R. Alguma sugestão?! Grato! []s

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Não está claro a sua pergunta. Se é número inteiro, zero tem apenas uma casa. É uma string? Pode colocar exemplos? 

Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

```
horario <- tibble(hora = c(1245L, 1342L, 1300L))

# A tibble: 3 × 1
   hora
  <int>
1  1245
2  1342
3  1300
```

Podes converter para a classe "datetime" (dttm) com a função `lubridate::parse_date_time()`.

Assim vc tem condições de fazer operações com datas/horários se for o propósito.

```
horario %>% 
  mutate(Time = lubridate::parse_date_time(hora, 'H:M'))


# A tibble: 3 × 2
   hora Time               
  <int> <dttm>             
1  1245 0000-01-01 12:45:00
2  1342 0000-01-01 13:42:00
3  1300 0000-01-01 13:00:00
>
```

Caso a intenção seja apenas apresentar visualmente, podes acrescentar a função `strptime()`

```
horario %>% 
  mutate(Time = lubridate::parse_date_time(hora, 'H:M'),
         Time = format(strptime(Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),'%H:%M'))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
   hora Time 
  <int> <chr>
1  1245 12:45
2  1342 13:42
3  1300 13:00
```

Ou, de forma ainda mais simples, utilizando a função `paste0()` aliada à função `str_extract()`

```
horario %>% 
  mutate(time = paste0(str_extract(hora, pattern = "^[0-9]{2}"), 
                      ":", 
                      str_extract(hora, pattern = "[0-9]{2}$")))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
   hora time 
  <int> <chr>
1  1245 12:45
2  1342 13:42
3  1300 13:00
```